# Facebook ad mobile for Android

Tags: android, facebook, ads

This is my first ad on facebook for Downloads.
I have 2 ads, one for iOS and other for Android, and I see the metrics for "Mobile App Installations" for iOS but on Android that value is 0, like if no one was installing it.
Is this a bug? Did a set wrong the ad for Android?

[image]

And in the settings for the ad I have:
[image]

THanks

Comment: Are you calling AppEventsLogger.activateApp in your app?

Comment: thank you, that was the issue